# Printing an array in python gives error "Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on."

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing some the Learning Data Science with Python on Common Lounge website. One of the first problems is to load a csv file and print row 5. My data loads and I can print the whole array but when I try to print just one row I get the error "Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on." What does this mean and how can I fix it? I'm using python3.

This also pops up on the side of Visual Studio Code:

```
"Unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found (file:///Users/a0015/Desktop/Programming/Commom_Lounge/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi)."
```

Here is the whole code I have, the error is from the print(dataSet[5,2]) line.

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


dataSet = pd.read_csv('/Users/a0015/Desktop/Programming/Commom_Lounge/diabetes.csv')

print(dataSet)

print(np.shape(dataSet))

print(dataSet[5,2])
```

Thanks for any help